# How to limit/set parallelism of QueueTriggers that get executed with Azure WebJobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have 5 QueueTrigger jobs within a single Function.cs file. 3 jobs must execute sequentially (synchronously) and 2 can process up to 16 items at a time.

From what I can decode from the documentation the AddAzureStorage queue configuration method only supports setting this parallelism for all the jobs:

```
.AddAzureStorage(queueConfig =>
{
 queueConfig.BatchSize = 1;
});
```

The above now sets that all jobs can process only one item at a time. If I set it to 16, then all jobs will run in parallel which is not what I want either.

Is there a way to set the BatchSize per QueueTrigger webjob or will I have to set it to 16 and use locks on those I don't want to run in parallel to achieve the desired behaviour?